# How to make a background color appear on top of a background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I got a `background-image` of a `<section>` in place and would like to have a `background-color` set up through it in order to give the image the dimmed effect. It isn't possible to use `opacity`as the effect will be extended to the children elements I have (a header in this case). I've used `rgba(0,0,0,.5)` on my section, but looks like the background-color can just appear behind the background-image.

Any ideas on how to make it cover the whole section while still behind the children elements?

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
}
/*Header*/

#header {
  width: 100%;
  background: url(../_img/new_background.jpg) no-repeat center center rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  background-size: cover;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /*For Safari 7 and 8*/
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
header {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
header h1,
header p:last-of-type {
  font-family: "Proxima Nova Extrabold";
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3.75em;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 + p {
  font-family: "Palatino";
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
<section id="header">
  <header>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Example</p>
    <p>Example</p>
  </header>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `:before` or `:after`

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
}
/*Header*/
 #header {
    width: 100%;
    background: url(http://zarech63.ru/sites/default/files/imagecache/product_full/product/motor-lodochnyy-suzuki-dt15as_623487.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    /*For Safari 7 and 8*/
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
}
#header:before{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
}


header {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
}
header h1, header p:last-of-type {
    font-family:"Proxima Nova Extrabold";
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 3.75em;
    text-align: center;
}
h1 + p {
    font-family:"Palatino";
    color: white;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
    <section id="header">
        <header>
             <h1>Example</h1>

            <p>Example</p>
            <p>Example</p>
        </header>
    </section>
```

Comment: I thought it could work, but the <header> inside #header ended up dimmed as well.

Comment: <header></header> - add - position: relative

Comment: I'd use this method personally. Pseudo-elements are fairly well supported now and it is a good use of them in order to achieve something without more markup. You can see the support: http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Abefore

Comment: p/s: Remember to use double colons for pseudo-elements, i.e. `::before` and `::after`.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple background images on an element. Use [CSS3 Linear Gradient](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#linear-gradients) image as the opaque overlay and place it in front of the JPEG image.

```css
#test {
  height: 300px;
  background:
    /* overlay */
    linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 100%),
    /* jpg img*/
    url("http://lorempixel.com/400/300/nature/5/");
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```